# Possible to add a new column to an Amazon SimpleDB domain with a default value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

You can dynamically put a new attribute on a single record in a domain, but that attribute remains null for all other records.  Is there an "update * set newattribute='defaultval" style statement that I can execute that will add the new attribute to all the other records?  I have a lot of records and would prefer not to loop over them all and do it programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any such option. We had a similar problem and had to do a hack. We added the Attribute_Name_Default as a separate attribute. We then wrote a wrapper for the Aws SimpleDB client which would check the default attribute for each attribute and assign the value to the original attribute before returning to actual code. Using dependency injection we did not have to change any code. If dependency injection is not an option just checkout the [aws client](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-java) from github make the change and use that jar as a dependency.

Comment: Accepting this since it doesn't appear there is any better way.  Thanks for the input.